# Stm32f4 Discovery Interrupts with program in RAM

Tags: c, interrupt, stm32

I'm trying to make a RTOS we used in school to work on my discovery board. In school we used a non commersial board and the RTOS was loaded into RAM. I have managed to load
it into RAM on the discovery board  but I have troubles with the timer interrupt.
  
I cannot see anywhere in the RTOS-code where the processor is told to jump to a specific address when the timer causes an interrupt. However there are addresses and function pointers initialized with these addresses. But how does the processor know how to jump to these addresses?  
The RTOS is not using SCB->VTOR to relocate the interrupt vector.

I removed all  unnecessary(i think and hope) code to show the problem in a smaller file.
To simplify even more I'm blinking a led on the timer interrupt.

If I can make this smaller program work then maybe I can make the RTOS work so any help is much appreciated. 
I made some comments in the code. 
So, what is missing in the code below to trigger the interrupt handler?

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_rcc.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_tim.h"

void timer5_init(void);
void led_init();
void init_all(void);

void startup(void) __attribute__((naked)) __attribute__((section (".start_section")) );

#define TIM5_IRQ_VECTOR         (0x2001C000+0x108)
#define TIMER5_INTERRUPT    void vect_TIM5( void ) 

TIMER5_INTERRUPT;

void startup(void) {
    asm volatile(
        " NOP\n"
        " LDR SP,=0x2001C000\n" // Set stack
        " BL main\n"
        ".L1: B .L1\n"  
            );
}

void main() {
    init_all();

    while (1) {
        // Toggle blue led
        GPIO_ToggleBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_15); // This works.   
        ms_delay2(250); 
    }
}

void init_all() {
    led_init();
    timer5_init();
}

TIMER5_INTERRUPT {

    if (TIM_GetITStatus(TIM5, TIM_IT_Update)) {
        // Toggle orange led
        GPIO_ToggleBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_13);
    TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM5, TIM_IT_Update);
    }

}

void timer5_init() {
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd( RCC_APB1Periph_TIM5, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockLPModeCmd( RCC_APB1Periph_TIM5, ENABLE);

    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure;  
    TIM_DeInit(TIM5);
    TIM_TimeBaseStructInit(&TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure);
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 840-1; 
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM5, &TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure);

    *((void (**)(void) ) TIM5_IRQ_VECTOR ) = vect_TIM5;// Why are they using vect_TIM5 here,
                                                         // instead of TIMER5_INTERRUPT? 
                                                        // Insn't vect_TIM5 just the definition
                                                       // of the macro? Why is this working?
    NVIC_SetPriority( TIM5_IRQn, 0x00);

    NVIC_EnableIRQ( TIM5_IRQn);
    TIM_SetCounter(TIM5, 0);    
    TIM_Cmd( TIM5, ENABLE);
    TIM_ITConfig( TIM5, TIM_IT_CC1, ENABLE);    
 }

void led_init() {
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitDef;
    GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_13 | GPIO_Pin_15;
    GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitDef);
}
```

LINKER SCRIPT:

```
MEMORY
{
    RAM (xrw) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 112K
}

SECTIONS
{

    .text :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);

        *(.start_section)          
        *(.text)                   
        *(.text.*)
        *(.rodata)                 
        *(.rodata*)
        *(.glue_7)
        *(.glue_7t)

         . = ALIGN(4);
     } >RAM


     .data  :
     {
        . = ALIGN(4);

         *(.data)
         *(.data.*)

         . = ALIGN(4);
     } >RAM


     .bss :
     {
         . = ALIGN(4);

          _sbss = .;

        *(.bss)
            *(.bss.*)
         *(COMMON)

         . = ALIGN(4);

        _ebss = . ;
     } >RAM

     PROVIDE ( end = _ebss );
     PROVIDE ( _end = _ebss );
 }
```

Comment: Uh, don't you have to have loader code in the startup assembly that copies the `main` code from flash to RAM, in order to execute there? If there is no code between the reset handler and `main()` that does this, then it won't get done. And yes, you're going to need to tell the NVIC to use vectors in RAM.

Comment: "Uh, don't you have to have loader code in the startup assembly that copies the main code from flash to RAM, in order to execute there?"  I forgot to mention that I use gdb to load the program into ram. I don't know why it works.

Comment: @unwind There is no vector table at all. Almost everything is wrong there. They try to do something which far beyond their knowledge. First they should learn how the micro works, then try to do complex system stuff.

Comment: Ok, then I must have stripped the original code too much. Thank you.